# How to setup network for GKE pods from two different projects? Shared vpc doesn't seem to work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, network-programming, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking, google-vpc

I have two projects in my Google Cloud. One of them has an endpoint I want to reach (published as Node Port). This port should be in internal network, but somehow accessible from second project.

My research of this problem got me into shared vpc networks. I created host and service projects. I set up shared vpc network. I created gke clusters in the same network and subnet. It seems like everything should be connected, but in reality there is still no connection.

Any ideas about reasons and further steps?

There are settings of shared subnet:
 Here you can see I have service and pods IP subranges for two gke clusters: lets denote them as gateway and tts. They share the same network and subnet, so I suppose pods should be able to communicate

There is an opened Nodeport on 10.0.37.97 as service in **tts** cluster (service project). It is accesible from pod in **tts** cluster (checked it with *kubectl exec bash*). And it is not accessible with the same script from pod in **gateway** cluster (host project).

here are clusters network settings

Networking for **tts** (service project)

```
Private cluster Disabled        
Network shared-net
Project: HOST_PROJECT_ID
Subnet  tts
Project: HOST_PROJECT_ID
VPC-native traffic routing  Enabled     
Cluster pod address range (default) 10.4.0.0/14     
Maximum pods per node   110     
Service address range   10.0.32.0/20        
Intranode visibility    Disabled        
NodeLocal DNSCache  Disabled        
HTTP Load Balancing Enabled     
Subsetting for L4 Internal Load Balancers   Disabled        
Control plane authorized networks   
Disabled
Network policy  Disabled        
Dataplane V2    Disabled
```

Networking for **gateway** (host project)

```
Private cluster Disabled        
Network shared-net      
Subnet  tts     
VPC-native traffic routing  Enabled     
Cluster pod address range (default) 10.192.0.0/14       
Maximum pods per node   110     
Service address range   10.196.0.0/20       
Intranode visibility    Disabled        
NodeLocal DNSCache  Disabled        
HTTP Load Balancing Enabled     
Subsetting for L4 Internal Load Balancers   Disabled        
Control plane authorized networks   
Disabled
Network policy  Disabled        
Dataplane V2    Disabled
```